# How to set up a Service Hook for the Kanban Board

Tags: azure-devops, slack, kanban

How can i configure VSTS to push notifications via a Service Hook when somebody moves a work item on the kanban board (State is unchanged)

I did try setting up a Trigger on State changes, but moving a item from "Doing " to "Done" does not raise any notification. If i check the History, the changed field is Named "Board Column" which is not available when setting up a Service Hook

Answer (score 1):

Service Hooks are a Project or Collection level connection between VS Team Services and an external system. You kanban columns are defined at your team level (multiple teams can have different kanban column settings).

Due to this difference in scope it's not possible to have alerts or webhooks act on the changes in the kanban state.

In the near future the ability to customize the state charts for workitems will land on Vs Team Services (announced this week on the Build Conference). After customizing the underlying state workflow, you'll be able to act on that through webhooks and the likes.

Comment: This is very very sad, would be perfect if VSTS would raise proper notifications for the board. Thanks anyway, customizing the WorkItems always means reduced compatibility.